# VueJS and Image CDNs: How to check when image is done being optimized through the Image CDN?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, cloudinary, imagekit

I might be over thinking this, but I got a an avatarprofile component that lets a user update their avatar image. I am using Google Cloud storage as the image hosting and then I am using an image CDN (imagekit) to handle the image optimization/caching. All works good...however, I do have a minor annoyance that I was wondering if someone could help me with:

First, here's my code (will help explain what I am having issue with):

```
    async avatarChangeHandler(e) {
      this.overlayShow = true //<-- show a loading indicator
      try {
        if (e.target.files.length) {
          this.image = await new Promise((resolve) => {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = (e) => {
              resolve(e.target.result)
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
          })
          await this.photoUpload() //<-- upload image to Google storage and return new image URL
          await this.updateAvatar() //<-- update user's profile in the database with new URL
          await this.$store.dispatch('getUserProfile', this.currentUser) //<-- grab updated profile
          console.log('updating...done')
          this.overlayShow = false //<-- terminate the loading indicator
```

The problem is that the user profile is updated with the new image URL and fetched faster than the image CDN...and so that means the `overlayShow` is already set to false and still shows the old image for a second or so (depending on level of optimization needed).

What can I do to make sure the `overlayShow` is not set to false until the image CDN is done with the new image? Thanks and I realize this may not be  feasible, but looking for advice or suggestions on approach. Thanks!

Comment: You store actions should be async too and you may have to wait until the processing is over. `this.overlayShow = false` should not be called until every calls are done (thanks to `await`). Alternative solution is to always get the callback from the APIs, check if it's status is set to `completed` or alike (ala processing is done) and **then**, update `overlayShow`.

Comment: Yea, I dont' know if there's a callback for the image API (imagekit.io), I'll check! Btw, My store action is async.